# Computing the quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $k$ be the homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ defined by $1 \mapsto (1 + 2\mathbb Z, -2)$. What is the quotient group of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ modulo the image of  $k$?

I first thought it would be easy... But it turns out to be quite nontrivial for me. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you guess what familiar group $G$ the quotient group might be isomorphic to? And if so, can you guess a formula for a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to G$ whose kernel is equal to the image of $k$? And if so, can you prove it?

Comment: That is the part I am stuck..I can't find some group this one might be isomorphic to. In fact I can't figure out what structure this quotient group has. Could you help me?

Comment: Have you determined the image of $k$, for starters?

Answer (score 0):

(Answering for my own practice. If someone sees this and lets me know if I am correct, much appreciated.)

The image of $k$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times 2\mathbb{Z}$. Since $(A \times B) / (H\times K) \cong A/H \times B/K$ if $H \unlhd A$ and $K \unlhd B$, we get,
$$
 \mathbb{Z}_2 \times 2\mathbb{Z} / \text{im}(k) \cong \{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2
$$